# How can I assign a css style to an on the fly created element?

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-css

I'm creating a rectangle in code and placing it inside a `HBox` created in scenebuilder. I then apply an already existing css style to it. The rectangle doesn't even show unless I specify a height and width when creating it (even though the css style already specifies height and width). However when I do manage to get it to show, the css style is not applied. I have no idea why this is happening and am hoping that someone can help me! Thanks

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
timesheetSlots.getChildren().addAll(rect);
rect.getStyleClass().add("timesheetSlot");
```

```css
.timesheetSlot{
    -fx-background-color: #ff6600;
    -fx-width: 20;
    -fx-height: 25;
    -fx-cursor: hand;
}
.timesheetSlot:hover{
    -fx-background-color: #ffffff;
}
.timesheetSlotSelected{
    -fx-background-color: #1Eff00;
    -fx-max-height: 25;
    -fx-max-width: 20;
    -fx-cursor: hand;
}
```

Comment: Did you add the CSS file to the scene? (Either through FXML or through the code)?

Comment: Yes I did I added it through the FXML file in scenebuilder...a label seems to pick up the css without any problem, makes me feel like there's something else that needs to be done when using shapes maybe ?

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple! Thanks to the both of you for your help.

Comment: Hmm. That doesn't work for me: [`Rectangle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#rectangle) has none of those properties. It works if you change `Rectangle` to `Region`, or change `-fx-background-color` to `-fx-fill` and set the size in code.

Answer (score 2):

You are using CSS properties, that are applicable for `Region`, but not for `Rectangle` ([see CSS reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#rectangle)). All supported properties of a `Node` are available through the [`Node.getCssMetaData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getCssMetaData--). Evaluating

```
new Rectangle().getCssMetaData().stream().map(CssMetaData::getProperty).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```

yields the following list (java 8 update 92):

```
-fx-arc-height
-fx-arc-width
-fx-blend-mode
-fx-cursor
-fx-effect
-fx-fill
-fx-focus-traversable
-fx-opacity
-fx-rotate
-fx-scale-x
-fx-scale-y
-fx-scale-z
-fx-smooth
-fx-stroke
-fx-stroke-dash-array
-fx-stroke-dash-offset
-fx-stroke-line-cap
-fx-stroke-line-join
-fx-stroke-miter-limit
-fx-stroke-type
-fx-stroke-width
-fx-translate-x
-fx-translate-y
-fx-translate-z
visibility
```

None of those allows you to style the `height` or `width` of a `Rectangle`. Also note that the `fill` of a `Rectangle` is assigned using the `-fx-fill` CSS property, not using `-fx-background-color`.

## Workarounds

### Using `Region`

You could simply replace the `Rectangle` with a `Region` and set the min and the max size to the width/height:

```css
.timesheetSlot{
    -fx-background-color: #ff6600;

    -fx-width: 20;
    -fx-min-width: -fx-width;
    -fx-max-width: -fx-width;

    -fx-height: 25;
    -fx-min-height: -fx-height;
    -fx-max-height: -fx-height;

    -fx-cursor: hand;
}
```

### Extending `Rectangle`

Alternatively extend the `Rectangle` class with a class that supports assigning the size using CSS, which requires some code, since you need add 2 new styleable properties:

```
public class StyleableRectangle extends Rectangle {

    private final StyleableDoubleProperty styleableWidth = new SimpleStyleableDoubleProperty(WIDTH_META_DATA, this, "styleableWidth");
    private final StyleableDoubleProperty styleableHeight = new SimpleStyleableDoubleProperty(HEIGHT_META_DATA, this, "styleableHeight");

    public StyleableRectangle() {
        bind();
    }

    public StyleableRectangle(double width, double height) {
        super(width, height);
        initStyleableSize();
        bind();
    }

    public StyleableRectangle(double width, double height, Paint fill) {
        super(width, height, fill);
        initStyleableSize();
        bind();
    }

    public StyleableRectangle(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        super(x, y, width, height);
        initStyleableSize();
        bind();
    }

    private void initStyleableSize() {
        styleableWidth.set(getWidth());
        styleableHeight.set(getHeight());
    }

    private final static List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> CLASS_CSS_META_DATA;

    private final static CssMetaData<StyleableRectangle, Number> WIDTH_META_DATA = new CssMetaData<StyleableRectangle, Number>("-fx-width", StyleConverter.getSizeConverter()) {

        @Override
        public boolean isSettable(StyleableRectangle styleable) {
            return !styleable.styleableWidth.isBound();
        }

        @Override
        public StyleableProperty<Number> getStyleableProperty(StyleableRectangle styleable) {
            return styleable.styleableWidth;
        }
    };

    private final static CssMetaData<StyleableRectangle, Number> HEIGHT_META_DATA = new CssMetaData<StyleableRectangle, Number>("-fx-height", StyleConverter.getSizeConverter()) {

        @Override
        public boolean isSettable(StyleableRectangle styleable) {
            return !styleable.styleableHeight.isBound();
        }

        @Override
        public StyleableProperty<Number> getStyleableProperty(StyleableRectangle styleable) {
            return styleable.styleableHeight;
        }
    };

    static {
        // combine already available properties in Rectangle with new properties
        List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> parent = Rectangle.getClassCssMetaData();
        List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> additional = Arrays.asList(HEIGHT_META_DATA, WIDTH_META_DATA);
        List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> own = new ArrayList(parent.size()+ additional.size());
        own.addAll(parent);
        own.addAll(additional);
        CLASS_CSS_META_DATA = Collections.unmodifiableList(own); 
    }

    // make metadata available for extending the class
    public static List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> getClassCssMetaData() {
        return CLASS_CSS_META_DATA;
    }

    @Override
    public List<CssMetaData<? extends Styleable, ?>> getCssMetaData() {
        return CLASS_CSS_META_DATA;
    }

    private void bind() {
        this.widthProperty().bind(this.styleableWidth);
        this.heightProperty().bind(this.styleableHeight);
    }


    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ----------------------- PROPERTY METHODS --------------------------------
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public final double getStyleableHeight() {
        return this.styleableHeight.get();
    }

    public final void setStyleableHeight(double value) {
        this.styleableHeight.set(value);
    }

    public final DoubleProperty styleableHeightProperty() {
        return this.styleableHeight;
    }

    public final double getStyleableWidth() {
        return this.styleableWidth.get();
    }

    public final void setStyleableWidth(double value) {
        this.styleableWidth.set(value);
    }

    public final DoubleProperty styleableWidthProperty() {
        return this.styleableWidth;
    }

}
```

sample CSS:

```css
.timesheetSlot {
    -fx-fill: brown;
    -fx-width: 20;
    -fx-height: 25;
    -fx-cursor: hand;
}
```